# Restricting users from installing software in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation, permissions

What are the steps I need to follow in order to restrict users on a Windows XP machine from being able to install software and other applications?

Answer (score 6):

Just don't give him administrative privileges. Putting a user into the "Users" group and *not* the "Administrators" group, should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Set the user account to restricted. A restricted user cannot install software. You can set the type of user in the user applet within the control panel. Which windows operating system are you using ?

Comment: I'm using windows XP

Comment: @Mask: If you are using XP-Pro, it has user groups/access-control as well.

Comment: This isn't quite true - I've seen limited/restricted users install Skype and Firefox in their temp folders and use them without issue. It depends partly on what the installer's doing.

Comment: Agreed, but nonetheless, to prevent *that,* you have to go much further. And restricting execution to only certain programs can't be done on a workstation OS.